# How to drag and drop the method of scenario class in the scenario?

Tags: ewam

I am working on a scenario and i can see only methods of my main class on the right side of scenario. But i cannot see the methods of the scenario class on the right side. How to make it visible so that i can drag and drop those methods on my scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Environment -> Options -> UI Builder and check Expert Scenario Design. You should be able to see the methods of your scenario on the right.[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np45Q.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZeXF.png)